# What is the technical term for a programming language's operator evaluation order?

Tags: operator-precedence, evaluation

Several procedures such as array destructuring in JavaScript or collection manipulation in Python have prompted me to evaluate an object's property or method to check if it even exists before proceeding, often resulting in the following pattern:

```
var value = collection.length

if value != null {
    if value == targetValue {
      /* do something */
    }
}
```

In an attempt to make "cleaner" code I want to do something like:

```
if value != null && value == targetValue {
      /* do something */
    }
```

or with a ternary operator:

```
var value = collection.length != null ? collection.length : 0
```

However, I'm never sure if the compiler will stop evaluating as soon as it resolves the first comparison to `null`, or if it'll keep going and produce an error. I can of course do small unit tests to find out but I'd prefer if I knew the right term to look up in any language's documentation. What is this term, or is it perhaps the same in all languages?

Comment: The property of `&&`, `||` and `?:` that ensures early termination is called *short-circuiting*, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) . It's quite consistent between languages.

In most languages, `&&` will only evaluate the second argument if the first was true, and `||` will only evaluate its second if the first was false.